# Getting IdentityProvider from REGISTRATION event Keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak, registration

I want to subscribe users to advert after they register on my app via identity provider (Facebook, Google etc.). I want to subscribe them only once - when they register on my app.

Also, I have in my code event listener, that catches some types of events - such as REGISTRATION event (the logic is provided like in the example here https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-register-event/6864/2 ).

So, **I'm looking the way to extract information of IdentityProvider when recieving REGISTRATION event to filter users** that needed to get advert flag automatically, is there any way to get it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to lookup the federated identities of the registered users. Something like this should work:

```java
RealmModel realm = session.realms().getRealm(event.getRealmId());
UserModel user = session.users().getUserById(realm, event.getUserId());
session.users().getFederatedIdentitiesStream(realm, user)
```

Comment: Thank you! The last question is:
what does .getIdentityProvider returns in FederatedIdentityModel class? It would be providerId or providerName? (for example, for facebook providerId is "facebook", but providerName is "Facebook".